# discordapp.com/api/users/@me/guilds sometimes responds with 401 UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: discord

In my application users login with Discord via OAuth and I save their token, expiration timestamp and refresh token to the session.  Every token issued is good for 7 days.  However a handful of users (maybe 2-5%) have been running into an issue where the token I have for them is not accepted by the Discord API and I see the following error:

```
GET https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me/guilds` resulted in a `401 UNAUTHORIZED` response:
{
  "code": 0,
  "message": "401: Unauthorized"
}
```

[View docs for this endpoint in Discord's API](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-current-user-guilds).

My first assumption is that their token is expired, so to confirm that I added the expiration time to my application's logs and have confirmed tokens don't expire until around `discord_token_expires_in 2018-01-28 05:12:37`.

With 95% of my users not experiencing an issue, I'm confident this isn't an issue with how the token is being sent, because then it would fail for everyone.  So I'm not sure what to look at next.

Comment: Was never able to find out a reliable solution to this, I just started redirecting users back to the auth screen when they encountered this error so they could relogin.

Answer (score 0):

There are several causes for bearer tokens becoming invalid before the expiry timestamp, including:

1. The bearer token being replaced with a new by refreshing it
2. A new bearer token was granted
3. The token being revoked, either by you or the user

[image: UI example]

There may be other causes, but at any rate you should anticipate that some bearer tokens are invalid, and you will want to attempt to refresh the token and/or request new user consent.